# Database Query and Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, database

I have a report on Excel that built using database query. I need to write comments on each row. When I refresh the file the comments don't stay on the same row and don't match the record. What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no easy way for that.

Best workaround I came up until now is to copy unique columns to a new sheet (I hope you have them) and enter comments there. Then use `VLOOKUP` to populate comments in the original sheet.